# Remove link after file is downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code below that consists of a img and a capture button. What i have done below is that whenever the user clicks on download it will prepend this link to my img src `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`.

What i'm trying to accomplish is that after the download is launched i want to remove that link `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` from my img src. Currently i have no idea on how to go about this any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```js
function sendData() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture'), {
    allowTaint: false,
    useCORS: true
  }).then(function(canvas) {
    $('#testaroni').attr('src', function(index, src) {
      return 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + src;
    });
    $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    $('#test').attr('download', 'Test.png');
    $('#test')[0].click();

  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="capture">
    <div class="jobs-panel">
      <img id="testaroni" data-target="#openly" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/4/49/Ash_Pikachu.png/250px-Ash_Pikachu.png" width="300" height="300">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="sendData()" ;>Capture!</button>
  <a id="test" href="#"></a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: couldn't you just do `$('#testaroni').attr('src', '')` after `$('#test')[0].click()`?

Comment: @Senju i want to add the link before the download and remove it after the download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var flag = true;
function sendData() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture'), {
    allowTaint: false,
    useCORS: true
  }).then(function(canvas) {
    $('#testaroni').attr('src', function(index, src) {
      return 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + src;
    });
    if(flag == true)
    {
        $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
        $('#test').attr('download', 'Test.png');
        $('#test')[0].click();
        $('#testaroni').attr('src','https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/4/49/Ash_Pikachu.png/250px-Ash_Pikachu.png');
        flag = false;
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work im trying to remove this link `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` after the download is launch

Comment: This line is to trigger download '$('#test')[0].click();' right?

Comment: Yes take a look at my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m2fj310t/ i have added your codes

Comment: It still doesn't

Comment: I tried that too @Gerfried. The issue is different. I got that. Updating my answer now.

Comment: @Tommy, check out the updated answer please. Its working now.

Comment: I think you want to the Capture button not to able to download the image after first download. Is that right? Or you also want to remove the image from the box?

Comment: No thats not what i want, As you can see from my code when i click on the Capture button it appends this link  `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`  to my img src. I want to remove this ` https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` link after the download is completed.

Comment: So the image will go away and there will be a blank white box. Is that okey?

Comment: Sorry i think i did explain it well, ok so after it appends this link to my img it becomes `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jobtech-images/sources/702b609f975ce112b0e53fb7af0652844dabb71a66904a52436cd9828b5e6ebb.png` i want it to go become this `https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jobtech-images/sources/702b609f975ce112b0e53fb7af0652844dabb71a66904a52436cd9828b5e6ebb.png` back to the original link after the download is complete

Comment: Sorry I am confused. The cartoon image is the one when page loads, and when we click on `Capture` button, the download occurs. And then you want to set the image with the link you posted. Am I right? I have changed my answer according to this.

Comment: There was a syntax error. I fixed that. Check the updated answer now.

Comment: Thank you @Tommy, for the up vote and accepting my answer. Happy to help.