# Remove partial img src

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code below that prepends a link to my `img src` when i click on the capture button and downloads the image.

The problem is i'm trying to make it so that after the download is launch it removes the link that i prepended into my img src so it will go back to this `https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/995985538556530690/7q_RKG2e_400x400.jpg`

is there an easy way to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="capture">
        <div class="jobs-panel">
            <img id="imageID"  src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/995985538556530690/7q_RKG2e_400x400.jpg"
                width="300" height="300">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="sendData()" ;>Capture!</button>
    <a id="test" href="#"></a>
</body>

</html>

<script>
 
 function sendData() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture'), {
    allowTaint: false,
    useCORS: true
  }).then(function(canvas) {
    $('#imageID').attr('src', function(index, src) {
      return 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + src;
    });
    $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    $('#test').attr('download', 'Test.png');
    $('#test')[0].click();

  });
}

</script>
```

Comment: what is canvas doing here and why do you need it. what is `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` as you are appending src to it, why not the image straight

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove link after file is downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587733/remove-link-after-file-is-downloaded) - you asked about pretty much the same issue not even an hour ago. Please don’t create duplicates, especially not in this frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Save the original `src` in a variable:

```
function sendData() {
  const origSrc = $('#imageID').attr('src');
```

And then set the `src` again after `click()`ing:

```
  $('#test')[0].click();
  $('#imageID').attr('src', origSrc);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/snymf90t/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="capture">
    <div class="jobs-panel">
      <img id="imageID" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/995985538556530690/7q_RKG2e_400x400.jpg" width="300" height="300">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="sendData()" ;>Capture!</button>
  <a id="test" href="#"></a>
</body>

</html>

<script>
  function sendData() {
    const origSrc = $('#imageID').attr('src');
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture'), {
      allowTaint: false,
      useCORS: true
    }).then(function(canvas) {
      $('#imageID').attr('src', function(index, src) {
        return 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + src;
      });
      $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
      $('#test').attr('download', 'Test.png');
      $('#test')[0].click();
      $('#imageID').attr('src', origSrc);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi may i ask what if i have like multiple different images like this https://jsfiddle.net/c6opyq3r/1/. The image is this fiddle is the same but what if they are different how do i store them in a variable?

Comment: I would change the script such that each `imageID` changed initializes a function (or a `setTimeout`, or a `Promise` resolution, etc, if it needs to be asynchronous), and that function resets the `src` of the passed element to the passed original `src` after the required operations are complete.